# SQLite3 ".tables" returns nothing

Tags: django, sqlite, ubuntu

I just installed Django 1.5.1 with Python 2.7.  SQLite3 comes with it.  I ran "python manage.py syncdb", which ran successfully and now I want to see what tables were created.  I ran the sqlite3 cmd line tool and in a sqlite prompt I did the following:

1. ATTACH '/home/thisUser/PyWorkspace/dbfile.db' AS dbf; //I noticed this got rid of the temp database
2. .databases confirms the name of the db is associated with dbfile.db, which is 2 directories up from my current directory that I ran the "sqlite3" command to start the sqlite cmd line.
3. .tables returns no tables!

What did I do wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.tables` shows master db tables. Try this:

```
$ sqlite3 /home/thisUser/PyWorkspace/dbfile.db
```

then

```
sqlite> .tables
```

Answer (score 2):

If your current working directory contains the database, then you can more simply use

`sqlite3 ./dbfile.db`

This saves you a lot of typing in path names. Alternately you can export the `PATH` at the start of your session.